# Prevent apache from automatically assigning file extension

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a LAMP server.  When user goes to the url http://mysite.com/helloworld, apache automatically decides to render helloworld.php instead of giving a 404 not found error.  I don't see any .htaccess file causing the rewrites.  I don't see any rewrite rules in the virtual host files.  How do I disable this automatic detection of a .php file and provide 404 error instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is the result of [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html).  If you haven't, make sure that Multiviews is disabled.

Comment: In my case it caused 404 exactly then, when a simmilar file was actually present. So e.g. I requested `/api/rest` and expected this to be rewriten according to rewriting rules. But I got 404 as long there was a file `api.php` in main directory! Switching off multiviews helped. Thx.